# Clear cache command gets an error error after installing api-platform.com

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to install api-platform but I'm  having problems after launching my composer install:

I follow the official docs for installation with:

```
composer req api
```

When I start the server or when I try to run `composer install` I get this error:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
```

and then a warning:

```
[WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:                               
!!                                                                                  
!!  
!!  In DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory.php line 31:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property  
!!    \DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance of D  
!!    octrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\Doc  
!!    trineBundle\Registry given, called in /var/www/test-api-sf/var/cache/dev/Co  
!!    ntainerPA69O1T/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1040                  
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  In DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory.php line 31:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property  
!!    \DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance of D  
!!    octrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\Doc  
!!    trineBundle\Registry given, called in /var/www/test-api-sf/var/cache/dev/Co  
!!    ntainerPA69O1T/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1040                  
!!                                                                                 
!!                                                                                  
!!   [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:                               
!!                                                                                  
!!  
!!  In DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory.php line 31:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property  
!!    \DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance of D  
!!    octrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\Doc  
!!    trineBundle\Registry given, called in /var/www/test-api-sf/var/cache/dev/Co  
!!    ntainerPA69O1T/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1040                  
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  In DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory.php line 31:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property  
!!    \DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance of D  
!!    octrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\Doc  
!!    trineBundle\Registry given, called in /var/www/test-api-sf/var/cache/dev/Co  
!!    ntainerPA69O1T/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1040                  
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!   // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug                       
!!   // true                                                                        
!!  
!!  
!!  In DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory.php line 31:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property  
!!    \DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance of D  
!!    octrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\Doc  
!!    trineBundle\Registry given, called in /var/www/test-api-sf/var/cache/dev/Co  
!!    ntainerPA69O1T/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1040                  
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
!!  
!!  2020-08-25T12:06:30+02:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property\DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in /var/www/test-api-sf/var/cache/dev/ContainerPA69O1T/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1040
```

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to circumvent it?

Comment: Had you maybe been using an older version of Doctrine before and when you added the api library it updated it? Something similar happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63188528/1196369

Comment: You're not alone, they open an issue on [symfony's github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37936)

Answer (score 1):

NEWS : It Seems that adding these lines in your composer.json at the conflict property works !

```
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*",
    "doctrine/common": ">=3.0",
    "doctrine/persistence": "<1.3"
},
```

---

So i got this problem since this morning and i looked for a solution and didn't found it so i made **my own DIY solution and it's working Pretty find for me Then i'm gonna share it :**

Firstly you need to go in the following path and open the file in it with your code editor:

```
C:\YOUR_PROJECT\vendor\api-platform\core\src\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property\DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory.php
```

Once you opened it, you need to **REPLACE the line 19** (*use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;*) with the following one:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry;
```

**AND THAT'S ALL FOLKS !**
[SCREENSHOT OF THE LINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYnUR.png)

**PS:** If you're still having issues or not founding the Vendor\api-platform, you just need to open the **composer.json** and temporary delete the Following line :

```
"cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
```

And run again the command:

```
composer req api
```

Answer (score 0):

we have the same problem since yesterday!
I tried to change the version of the bundle, to an older version . But without any successful result.

Current dependency:

```
"api-platform/api-pack": "^1.2"
```

But the problem is solved on GitHub. To be tested...
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37936

---

UPDATE: We have to wait for a release of api-platform bundle.
https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3683

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily, you can add this to composer.json :

```
"conflict": {
    ...
    "doctrine/common": ">=3.0",
    "doctrine/persistence": "<1.3"
}
```

It works for me.
https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3683#issuecomment-681039267

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but when i add the following lines

`"conflict": { ... "doctrine/common": ">=3.0", "doctrine/persistence": "<1.3" }`
in my composer.json file the problem was resolved